# Why does not the coordinate of the graph match the dataframe?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, ggplot2

I drawing the plot of Île-de-France with

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/Stat_Cons/main/station.csv")[1:3]
df2 <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c('V1','V2'), crs = 2154)

df3 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = df2,
          size = 0.1,
          color = "lawngreen",
          fill = "lawngreen") +
  ggtitle("Stations")

plot(df3)
```

My dataframe is

```
Simple feature collection with 25338 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 48.66986 ymin: 2.012258 xmax: 49.05865 ymax: 2.782492
projected CRS:  RGF93 / Lambert-93
First 10 features:
    X                  geometry
1   1 POINT (48.85153 2.637754)
2   2 POINT (48.83918 2.638771)
3   3 POINT (48.85163 2.621466)
4   4  POINT (48.9135 2.482264)
5   5 POINT (48.99439 2.523624)
6   6 POINT (48.88744 2.325725)
7   7 POINT (48.85602 2.624391)
8   8  POINT (48.8531 2.281198)
9   9 POINT (49.00259 2.535003)
10 10 POINT (48.84394 2.627361)
```

My plot is

[image]

Could you explain why the coordinate from the plot is somewhere `5.98°S 1.7°W`? I expect it would be somewhat `48.85°N 2.63°E`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the following code line:

```
df2 <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c('V1','V2'), crs = 2154)
```

I notice that the crs is defined as 2154, which is a projected coordinate system in meters (Lambert-93 in RGF93). However, your points are actually geographic coordinates, and you need to tell that to the system. A reprojection can be done later in the process, but at this step, you need to use a geographic crs, such as EPSG:4171 for geographic RGF93, or EPSG:4326 for WGS84. Otherwise the system thinks your coordinates such as `(48.85153 2.637754)` are meters in Lambert 93, and it lands you in the Atlantic Ocean near Africa.

One more thing, check the axis order on the resulting plot. I can't verify at the moment but it is possible that by default your coords will be interpreted as `('longitude','latitude')`, so you may have to swap your two fields here to `('V2','V1')`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I got it.

Comment: Your answer means so much to our project :))